# Changing state before it renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am having an issue where empty props is being passed from the Parent component to the Child component. I believe it's because I am trying to set the state of my data in a function rather than in a constructor (for Parent component); I only want to set the state of data if the *"Display"* button is clicked.

How can I change the **this.state.data** to **this.props.data.dataList[rowIndex]** right away when I click "Display" button, and so that it re-renders with the changed state?

I keep getting undefined or a null pointer because my **this.props.data** does not exist in Child component because it renders before the *"Display"* button is clicked.

I have tried conditional rendering, and if possible I want to try to avoid it.

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        };
        this.handleDisplay = this.handleDisplay.bind(this);
    }

    columns = [
      {dataField: '..', text: '...',
        formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.handleDisplay(rowIndex)}>Display</Button>
                </div>
            );
        }
        }, 
      {dataField: '..', text: '...' },  
      {dataField: '..', text: '...' }, 
      {dataField: '..', text: '...'}];

    handleDisplay(rowIndex){
            this.setState({
            index: rowIndex,
            data: this.props.data.dataList[rowIndex]
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable
                    hover
                    condensed={true}
                    bootstrap4={true}
                    keyField={'id'}
                    data={this.props.data.dataList}
                    columns={this.columns}
                />
                <Child data={this.state.data}/>
            </div>


        );

    }

}

export class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }   

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            data: this.props.data
        })
    }

    render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col}>
                <Form.Label>Label Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control name="labelName" value={this.props.data.labelName}/>
                .
                .
                ..
                ...
                ....
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
    </div>
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: Move columns to constructor, such as, this.state = {  data: {  columns: [...]  } };

Comment: And I would recommend you to learn what declarative ui component means, and how to create declarative ui components that reacts to data. This would answer your question about conditional showing.

Comment: I would say, your way of doing things is definetely all wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply do something like this:

```
{this.state.data && <Child data={this.state.data}/>}
```

This way, your Child component will only be rendered if `this.state.data` is truthy (do not forget that an empty object is truthy (`!!{} === true`), thus you should start `data` on your state with something falsy)

However, it is a good practice to have this verification inside your `Child` component as well. You can have the same approach of doing the validation inside the render method and display nothing if the data is empty